# Are there any DNA base sequences that are shared by every living being that we know of? And if yes, are some of those sequences "silent"?

Tags: genetics, dna

In "every living being" I am not including viruses as another question already answered that.

I have read that some part of the DNA sequences of humans and other animals/plants are "silent" as in not affecting the phenotype of a species.

I was wondering if there was some part of those silent sequences that are also common to all living being.

Comment: What is your length cut-off? Any arbitrary sequence of 10 base pairs is likely to be found in a 1 Mb pair genome, if you are talking about exact matches. And where exactly did you read this? We need to be able to check and assess your source.

Comment: I see, sorry about that it's my first time here. My source about the non-coding bit is on the french Wikipedia I'm afraid but here it is: [link](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9nome) The paragraph titled "Régions non-codantes" talks about the region of the DNA that are not coding. About the size of the sequence, I don't really know but I would say any length that seems to be long enough for not being just a probable occurrence but something a bit more "meaningful". I understand that this is probably way too vague.

Comment: It’s ok. I can read French. I’ll have a look at it when I have a moment. Can you give me the exact French text (just the start will do) so I can locate the section you mention. (For the benefit of everyone, I’ll answer in English.)

Comment: Yes, so the paragraph talking about non-coding sequences is titled "Régions non-codantes" and more specifically the paragraph starting with "En plus des gènes, les génomes contiennent en effet souvent des pseudogènes. Ce sont des séquences qui ont de nombreuses caractéristiques des gènes (séquences codantes, séquence promoteur, signaux d'épissage…), mais qui ne sont pas fonctionnelles et ne conduisent donc pas à la production d'une protéine." is the one that specifically talks about the parts of the DNA that cannot produce a protein.

Comment: OK. I'll can address that when I get a moment. But where does it mention "sequences shared by every living being"?

Comment: Oh it doesn't mention that, this article is only about some sequences being silent. Sorry if that was unclear but that was the point of my question: Are there any silent sequences that are shared by everything alive?

Comment: The answer to that is No. I'll write you an explanatory answer but I need to see what parts of it have been covered in previous questions. It may be the weekend before I have time to do it, though.

Comment: No worries at all, thanks for taking the time to consider my question!